# Crash report : Critercism crash log

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have received the following crash report from criticism tracker. I can not understand for which it happens. I have not found from my device. It occurs from live app.

libobjc.A.dylib 0x39e19b66 objc_msgSend + 6

```
UIKit 0x31f136ff -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 347

UIKit 0x31fa7f83 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 587

UIKit 0x31fa7ab1 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 573

UIKit 0x31f86779 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 1333 
UIKit 0x31f86233 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 295

SureSMSClient 0x00024b55 0x00005000 + 129877

UIKit 0x320160cb -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1079

UIKit 0x320c9863 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 215

UIKit 0x31f79781 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 317

UIKit 0x31ef17bb _afterCACommitHandler + 431

CoreFoundation 0x2f73ff69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21

CoreFoundation 0x2f73d8f7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 287

CoreFoundation 0x2f73dc43 __CFRunLoopRun + 739

CoreFoundation 0x2f6a8471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525

CoreFoundation 0x2f6a8253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107

GraphicsServices 0x343af2eb GSEventRunModal + 139

UIKit 0x31f5d845 UIApplicationMain + 1137

SureSMSClient 0x0000628f 0x00005000 + 4751
```

Please suggest me what I will do.

Comment: On what action does your app is crashing? Provide some code. I guess it is coz of Your tableview didselectrow post some code

Answer (score 0):

In Targets go to the build phase
 add the CoreGraphics framework

Comment: you have added the libz 1.2.5

Comment: I have added the libz.dylib. For the lower version of libz, above crash occures. i ask you caused, I have not received any crash for that. only one user get this crash in live version.